# NoMethodError: undefined method `sort` from Twilio voice example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, ruby-on-rails-5, twilio-api

I am trying to set up an example Twilio Rails project that calls a person. I am following the tutorial associated with [this repo](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/clicktocall-rails) and have basically a carbon copy of the codebase. I'm getting an error that I think is from this line `@validator = Twilio::Util::RequestValidator.new(@@twilio_token)`.

Here's my `twilio_controller.rb`

```
class TwilioController < ApplicationController
  # Before we allow the incoming request to connect, verify
  # that it is a Twilio request
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  before_action :authenticate_twilio_request, :only => [
    :connect
  ]

  @@twilio_sid = ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
  @@twilio_token = ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
  @@twilio_number = ENV['TWILIO_NUMBER']
  @@api_host = ENV['TWILIO_HOST']

  # Render home page
  def index
    render 'index'
  end

  def voice
    response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Say "Yay! You're on Rails!", voice: "alice"
      r.Sms "Well done building your first Twilio on Rails 5 app!"
    end
    render :xml => response.to_xml
  end

  # Handle a POST from our web form and connect a call via REST API
  def call
    contact = Contact.new
    contact.user_phone  = params[:userPhone]
    contact.sales_phone = params[:salesPhone]

    # Validate contact
    if contact.valid?

      @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new @@twilio_sid, @@twilio_token
      # Connect an outbound call to the number submitted
      @call = @client.calls.create(
        :from => @@twilio_number,
        :to => contact.user_phone,
        :url => "#{@@api_host}/connect/#{contact.encoded_sales_phone}" # Fetch instructions from this URL when the call connects
      )

      # Let's respond to the ajax call with some positive reinforcement
      @msg = { :message => 'Phone call incoming!', :status => 'ok' }

    else

      # Oops there was an error, lets return the validation errors
      @msg = { :message => contact.errors.full_messages, :status => 'ok' }
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @msg }
    end
  end

  # This URL contains instructions for the call that is connected with a lead
  # that is using the web form.
  def connect
    # Our response to this request will be an XML document in the "TwiML"
    # format. Our Ruby library provides a helper for generating one
    # of these documents
    response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Say 'FUCK.', :voice => 'alice'
      # r.Dial params[:sales_number]
    end
    render text: response.text
  end


  # Authenticate that all requests to our public-facing TwiML pages are
  # coming from Twilio. Adapted from the example at
  # http://twilio-ruby.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/validation.html
  # Read more on Twilio Security at https://www.twilio.com/docs/security
  private
  def authenticate_twilio_request
    twilio_signature = request.headers['HTTP_X_TWILIO_SIGNATURE']
    # Helper from twilio-ruby to validate requests.
    @validator = Twilio::Util::RequestValidator.new(@@twilio_token)

    # the POST variables attached to the request (eg "From", "To")
    # Twilio requests only accept lowercase letters. So scrub here:
    post_vars = params.reject {|k, v| k.downcase == k}

    is_twilio_req = @validator.validate(request.url, post_vars, twilio_signature)

    unless is_twilio_req
      render :xml => (Twilio::TwiML::Response.new {|r| r.Hangup}).text, :status => :unauthorized
      false
    end
  end

end
```

Error image:

[image]

I am using `ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin15]` and `Rails 5.1.0`.

Comment: It failed at line 85 inside `authenticate_twilio_request`, for undefined method `sort`. However looking at your code, you didn't use `sort` inside `authenticate_twilio_request`, did you perhaps edit your code above?

Comment: Seems like `ActionController::Parameters #sort` is already removed in Rails 5.1, reason I quote "as `ActionController::Parameters` no longer inherits from hash" when I tried to `sort` in Rails 5.0.3 and got that deprecation warning.

Comment: Upon further inspection, because I couldn't see any trace of `sort` on your code above, I found the line that causes the error from https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/blob/ac2680cde6913af94e24fb24ee27bb28ffa2602b/lib/twilio-ruby/util/request_validator.rb:`data = url + params.sort.join` which is eventually called by your `is_twilio_req = @validator.validate(request.url, post_vars, twilio_signature)`, so see my answer below for a fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is most likely failing at `is_twilio_req = @validator.validate(request.url, post_vars, twilio_signature)` because upon inspection of the [gem's code](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/blob/ac2680cde6913af94e24fb24ee27bb28ffa2602b/lib/twilio-ruby/util/request_validator.rb), it is failing at `sort` below

> data = url + params.sort.join

This is because in Rails 5.1, `ActionController::Parameters` no longer inherits from `Hash`, so `Hash` methods like `sort` ([see `Hash` docs](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash)) will no longer work.

You will need to convert `params` into hash explicitly:

```
def authenticate_twilio_request
  twilio_signature = request.headers['HTTP_X_TWILIO_SIGNATURE']
  @validator = Twilio::Util::RequestValidator.new(@@twilio_token)

  # convert `params` which is an `ActionController::Parameters` object into `Hash`
  # you will need `permit!` to strong-params-permit EVERYTHING so that they will be included in the converted `Hash` (you don't need to specifically whitelist specific parameters for now as the params are used by the Twilio gem)
  params_hash = params.permit!.to_hash

  post_vars = params_hash.reject {|k, v| k.downcase == k}

  is_twilio_req = @validator.validate(request.url, post_vars, twilio_signature)

  unless is_twilio_req
    render :xml => (Twilio::TwiML::Response.new {|r| r.Hangup}).text, :status => :unauthorized
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you! I will give it a shot when I get home from work

Comment: @Sticky No problem! :)

Comment: Thank for the answer @Jay-ArPolidario! I actually have a PR open to fix this in the gem and I've just nudged the team responsible for the libraries internally to try to get this looked at. Hopefully you can continue to the use the gem as intended soon.

Comment: @philnash I'm glad I could be of some help! :)